# while starting Tomcat 8 service [java.lang.IllegalStateException: No output folder] occurs on eclipse

Tags: jakarta-ee

When I starting Tomcat 8 service exception error occurs on eclipse.Following error displayed.Kindly help me to resolve this problem.

```
Feb 13, 2015 12:03:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
        SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: No output folder] with root cause
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: No output folder
            at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.createOutputDir(JspCompilationContext.java:662)
            at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getOutputDir(JspCompilationContext.java:194)
            at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getClassFileName(JspCompilationContext.java:510)
            at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.isOutDated(Compiler.java:444)
            at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.isOutDated(Compiler.java:408)
            at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:563)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:356)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
```